# Alexa failure to install

Tags: software-installation

I keep getting this error, can anyone advise please?

```
Cloning into 'alexa-rpi'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 293, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (293/293), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (201/201), done.
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peerB | 3.34 MiB/s   
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Bit hard to work out what you are doing without the command but this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977206/fatal-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: When do you get this error? Do you execute a command? What command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying. I modified git to https:// in the script and overcame the problem

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.